# Server Error in '/' Application. after moving VM

Tags: farm

After migrating SQL and application sharepoint 2013 VM to new server, the message when accessing Intranet is:
[image: Server Error in '/' Application]

Then I run the Sharepoint Products Migration Wizzard and error is:

[image: Failed to detect]

Any ideas? Should I remove server from farm?

EDIT: trying to remove server from farm, I am getting error:
[image]

Comment: Do you mantain these machines in same Domain Controller and with same IP address and hostnames?

Comment: yes, same domain controller for sql and configuration servers

Comment: How were these migrated? Or did you just move the VMs from one VM host to another?  I'd check out SQL, it kinda looks like the SP server can't connect to the config DB.

Comment: they were exported from Hyper-V and imported in totally different Hyper-V server